# Find out which album(s) a photo is in in Google Photos API

Tags: google-api, google-photos, google-photos-api

I am using the Google Photo API, https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest
I am using [get](https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/get) successfully to get information about a media (a photo). However, I really really need to know WHICH albums the photo is in (it cam be multiple).

Is there any way to do this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get all albums first and then get photos through https://developers.google.com/photos/library/reference/rest/v1/mediaItems/search
by adding the parameter of albumId.